# Setting up environment variable in linux

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

While installing UIMA I got this steps in readme file

```
* Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your JRE installation you would like to use for UIMA.  
* Set UIMA_HOME to the apache-uima directory of your unpacked Apache UIMA distribution
* Append UIMA_HOME/bin to your PATH

* Please run the script UIMA_HOME/bin/adjustExamplePaths.bat (or .sh), to update 
  paths in the examples based on the actual UIMA_HOME directory path. 
  This script runs a Java program; 
  you must either have java in your PATH or set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to a 
  suitable JRE.
```

I opened /etc/environment and perfomed this changes:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/UIMA_HOME/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"
UIMA_HOME="/root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/UIMA_SDK_1.4.5"
```

after that executed:

```
UIMA/UIMA_SDK_1.4.5/bin# ./documentAnalyzer.sh
```

which gave this error:

```
./documentAnalyzer.sh: 2: .: Can't open /bin/setUimaClassPath.sh
```

documentAnalyzer.sh code :

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$UIMA_HOME/bin/setUimaClassPath.sh"
if [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "" ];
then
  JAVA_HOME=$UIMA_HOME/java/jre
fi
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -cp "$UIMA_CLASSPATH" -Xms128M -Xmx900M "-Duima.home=$UIMA_HOME" "-Duima.datapath=$UIMA_DATAPATH" -DVNS_HOST=$VNS_HOST -DVNS_PORT=$VNS_PORT "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$UIMA_HOME/Logger.properties" com.ibm.uima.reference_impl.application.docanalyzer.DocumentAnalyzer
```

What is the mistake here? I guess I set environment variable correctly

Comment: your `PATH="...:/UIMA_HOME/bin"` line is either a copy paste error or you are missing a `$`

Comment: it should be `PATH="...:$UIMA_HOME/bin"`

Comment: please do `cat "$UIMA_HOME/bin/setUimaClassPath.sh"` and see whether there are error messages.

Comment: getting this `cat: /bin/setUimaClassPath.sh: No such file or directory` @lesmana

Comment: it seems that `$UIMA_HOME` is not defined. this can have many causes. ultimately the solution is to make sure that the variable is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers given about adding the $ to the variable UIMA_HOME in your PATH variable are correct, but, I think you are also lacking the EXPORT command for your variables. 
Look, after you set their values, you should also writhe this in /etc/environment:

```
export UIMA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

That way, you would be able to use them later (always remember to fix the PATH variable with the $UIMA_HOME as well).

If this does not work, try rebooting your computer after setting the variables as I said.

In the case that does not work either, try repeating the process and in a console (after doing everythin all over again) try using the following command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Fianlly, if that does not work, try setting the variables in the file called /etc/profile (do the same process: setting the varialbes and exporting them), and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The order of variable assignments in your /etc/environment is wrong; in order to use `$UIMA_HOME` in the `PATH=`..., you have to define `UIMA_HOME` afore, e. g.

```
UIMA_HOME="/root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/UIMA_SDK_1.4.5"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"
```